# Is it possible to use 1column extract to 4 column

Tags: sql

i don't sure this to possible i don't have idea
this my tables : tbchecked

[id] [status]

001  present

001  present

001  absent

001  absent

001  leave

001  present

001  present

002  present

002  absent

002  leave

it is possible? to output in gridview1 how to query?

[id] [present] [absent] [leave]

001     4         2        1

002     1         1        1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
select id,
sum(case when status = 'present' then 1 else 0 end) as present,
sum(case when status = 'absent'  then 1 else 0 end) as absent,
sum(case when status = 'leave'   then 1 else 0 end) as leave
from tbchecked
group by id
```